# IONIC - ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage

Tags: ios, angular, ionic3

I am trying to upload iOS build, but I got an warning **Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.**

Please help me out how to fix this warning because as per my understanding in future my app will getting rejected.

Quickest response is highly appreciable.

Comment: At the moment this is just a warning - apps developed with various tools are getting this warning - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Itms-90809 The ionic maintainers will need to replace whatever functionality is using `UIWebView` (Note that since ios8 using WKWebView has been recommended)

Comment: Thanks for your comment....but right now it is warning and most probably after launching of iOS 13 it will become an error which cause Apple Reject of my app that's why I am worried about it. If you got any solution please let me know.

Comment: The cordova team yesterday released 2019-11-25 a release cordova-ios@5.1.0

This release resolves the ITMS-90809 alert from the apple store.

   1) cordova platform remove ios
    2) cordova platform add ios@5.1.0
    
    3) Add <preference name = "WKWebViewOnly" value = "true" /> to your config.xml file
    
   4) Run "cordova prepare ios" to apply the changes.

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/11/25/cordova-ios-release-5.1.0.html#comment-4702612854